# In Visual Studio, what does the "Clean" command do?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

You know, the one that outputs this=>

> ------ Clean started: Project: Foo.Bar, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   ========== Clean: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

What it is cleaning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2005 Clean Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480608/visual-studio-2005-clean-solution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2005 Clean Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480608/visual-studio-2005-clean-solution)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The output directories - it removes the code that it's previously built.

It doesn't remove the bin/obj directories themselves (or the Debug/Release directories beneath them), just the actual .exe, .dll, etc files. Unfortunately this makes it less useful for my usual use of cleaning up output directories: when I want to zip up the source code. As the Clean action doesn't do this, I usually just delete the bin and obj directories directly.

Comment: Good point about not removing the directories entirely.  Its mostly moot for me because Subversion has the export command that works well (at least if you haven't added the bin, obj, *.suo, *.user, etc. files to the repository that is).  But, yeah, it would be nice to see that feature.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in VS 2013, the Clean Solution command will only affect the currently active configuration (e.g.: if your solution is set to Debug configuration, Clean Solution will not do anything to the files in the Release folder).

Comment: There is an extension called CleanProject, which allows you to do a full clean (delete bin, obj, ...): https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bca632e0-3948-43c8-b337-da47275717b6

Comment: Note that the Clean operation does not delete referenced assemblies that have CopyLocal set to True. You can edit your project file to add an "AfterClean" MSBuild target that does additional cleanup.

Comment: I read somewhere that it only affects build output files and does not include files created by other tools or custom build events. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dercsár: I suspect so, but I'd have to check (which you could do too). Most of the time I'd expect VS to be the tool responsible for everything under bin and obj though.

Answer (score 36):

Why not look for yourself?  Open up Microsoft.Common.Targets (found under %windir%\Microsoft.NET) and you'll see a section like so:

```
<!--
============================================================
                                    Clean

Delete all intermediate and final build outputs.
============================================================
-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <CleanDependsOn>
        BeforeClean;
        CleanReferencedProjects;
        UnmanagedUnregistration;
        CoreClean;
        CleanPublishFolder;
        AfterClean
    </CleanDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target
    Name="Clean"
    Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' "
    DependsOnTargets="$(CleanDependsOn)" />
```

Keep reading to see exactly what each of those sub-targets does.  (Some, of course, are just stubs for the user to override).

Personally, I like to see what shenanigans my fancy-pants IDE is up to behind my back.  To this end, I'd recommend increasing the amount of info written to the Output window.  Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Build & Run -> MSBuild verbosity -> change from "Minimal" to "Normal" or "Detailed."

Try your Clean operation again and watch the output now!  Correlating what you see to the *.targets files is a good way to start learning MSBuild.

Answer (score 15):

It goes through your output directories and deletes any build related files in them.

I think you can also configure this by going to the Project's properties in

Configuration Properties -> General, under "Extensions to Delete on Clean"

Comment: I'm quite sure i knew this. Just haven't find a good use case for it and therefore - forgot. Couldn't understand how to ask it properly to google.

Comment: One good use case for it is if you want to zip up your project and send it to another programmer via email.  It keeps the size down, and removes the executable files, which email systems don't like very much.

Comment: "Extensions to Delete on Clean" is only found in c++ project properties, not managed projects.

Answer (score 4):

removes all the files associated with the build, output directories

Answer (score 4):

People use a 'clean' to force a complete rebuild from source.  Your compiler doesn't rebuild every file every time if it hasn't changed.

Comment: Firstly to clarify on this, a clean doesn't do any building.  A clean ensures a full build if you do a subsequent build using the 'build' option in VS.  If you 'rebuild' in Visual Studio then everything will be rebuilt, as this does a clean first anyway.    I personally always rebuild, to avoid potential issues.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, because it is giving the actual reason why