# How can I send a whole .Net project as attachment via gmail?

Tags: .net, zip, gmail, executable

I'm frequently working with students on their .Net coding assignments.  I'd like to email the code to them when we're done.  The easiest thing would be just to zip the project folder and send the whole thing, but gmail always strips out my attachments because they contain executables. Generally it's just the myproject.vshost.exe or something innocuous like that, but it's a pain to have to find an alternative upload location and then email the link to that.  Has anyone been able to find a workaround that would allow me to send attachments like this via gmail?

I suspect the answer to this is "nope, it's not possible," but I'll ask anyway

Comment: I strip file extensions when I need to attach executables, for example Project1.zip becomes Project1

Comment: How about doing a Clean solution before zipping?

Comment: if its not a .zip it works, +1 to novikov

Comment: Not an immediate fix...  But I had a prof setup a cvs repo that was used to hand in assignments. Today I suppose you might use git or hg.  In any case it was the best homework submission setup I had experienced as a student.  And everyone received some real vocational skills with source control.

Comment: Not really a programming question... I think it belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Ermm ... *you don't*? You set up a repo of some sort ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another answer is to encrypt the zip file or rar file.   If you use winrar you can setup a password and choose "encrypt file names".   This will bypass the gmail filter.

Comment: Using 7-zip would be a great alternative as well (http://www.7-zip.org). I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Yea 7-zip is awesome.  I do believe the poster a few down might be correct about the rename the zip as well,  worth a try.

Comment: I zipped using the 7z format and it worked great!  Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

If you zip up everything in your project except the /bin and the /obj folders, you should be okay sending the project to them. When they get the project, they simply need to compile it again to get the executable, but all the code will already be there.

Comment: as long as they don't have binary dependencies this works well

Comment: DLL binaries should send without a problem. Or were you referring to EXE binaries that were being included in the project?

Comment: dll's are "executable" by way of the gmail filter, if you put a dll in a zip file, it won't send, but if you say depend on a lib directory with nhibernate in it, then you need to find a new way around it.

Comment: Interesting. I had a couple of DLL libraries in the sample I mailed myself and it went through just fine if there were no EXEs in it. Are the DLLs giving you grief?

Comment: This is a good solution, but it adds an additional step. It was easier just to use an alternative archive format.  It may not be future proof as google may eventually begin scanning 7z files for executables as well, but when that time comes I can switch back to this method.

Comment: Best answer.  Love it. Live it.  Hate it.

Comment: So the end user needs a compiler? In all likelihood that's probably not going to go smoothly. Using a file sharing site would be my solution. Compiler, he he.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for .VB projects since .VB is one of the blocked file extensions.

Answer (score 7):

Rename the file extension e.g project.zip to project.zub
This trick worked for me...

Answer (score 6):

Gmail will allow you to send a zip file as long as its not named zip. so if you name it .zop and tell them to rename it then unzip it, it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: If I rename the zip file to zip2, I can send it, but if the recipient is also using gmail, I receive a security warning as response and he never receives the mail.  Looks like gmail is looking at the file signature to identify it (first bytes...) and try to unzip if it detects a zip file, even if we rename it .jpg.

Answer (score 5):

Just zip your whole project and upload it to the google drive. After uploading it into the drive you will get an option of sharing setting and through that you can feed the email id of the person whom you want to send it.. 
That link will be sent to that person and he/she can download it easily...

Enjoy!

Comment: Much simpler this way, now that Google are blocking .js files inside .zips

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using some flavour of of Visual Studio - does [Visual Studio's clean command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603242/in-visual-studio-what-does-the-clean-command-do) do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

take a look on this
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c736dedf-bbed-454a-8073-89993ca46902
That tool allows you to create Backups (zip files) from solutions or projects automatically
and you can also send code chunk directly from VS to any Email Client, it's pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

very simple. 
you can zip the project , change the file extension to " .txt " and send it happily! 
just tell your students to change the file extension again to ".zip"and then unzip it! :) 
works with yahoo mail. never used gmail though. please try and let us know the results.